# Adobe Fireworks CS5 Installation fails with Error Code 7

Tags: installation, adobe-cs5, adobe-fireworks

I have problems installing Adobe Fireworks CS5 and it fails with Error Code 7.

What could be causing this?

Comment: You've got to provide more information if you expect any sort of useful response.

Comment: What is your **problem**? Please be specific. You didn't gave us any clue. How can we read your mind?